# Sort (and sorted) not sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a data file that's built the following way:

source_id, target_id, impressions, clicks

on which I add the following columns:

- pair - a tuple of the source and target
- CTR - basically clicks/impressions
- Lower Bound
- Upper Bound

Lower/Upper bound are calculated values (it's irrelevant to my question, but for the curious ones  [these are the bounds for the Wilson confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029645/2594546).

The thing is, I'm trying to sort the list by the lower bound (position = 6), descending. Tried several things (sort/sorted, using lambda vs. using itemgetter, creating a new list w/o the header and try to sort just that) and still it appears nothing changes. I have the code below.

```
import csv
from math import sqrt
from operator import itemgetter

#----- Read CSV ----------------------------------------------------------------
raw_data_csv  = open('rawdile', "rb")
raw_reader = csv.reader(raw_data_csv)

#  transform the values to ints.
raw_data = []
for rownum,row in enumerate(list(raw_reader)):
    if rownum == 0:                                                             # Header
        raw_data.append(row)
    else:
        r = []                                                            # Col header
        r.extend([int(x) for x in row])                                     # Transforming the values to ints
        raw_data.append(r)



# Add cols for pairs (as tuple) and CTR
raw_data[0].append("pair")


for row in raw_data[1:]:
    row.append((row[0],row[1]))         # tuple
#    row.append(float(row[3])/row[2])    # CTR



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


z = 1.95996398454005


def confidence(n, clicks):

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    phat = float(clicks) / n
    l_bound = ((phat + z*z/(2*n) - z * sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n))        # lower bound
    u_bound = ((phat + z*z/(2*n) + z * sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n))        # upper bound
    return phat, l_bound, u_bound


raw_data[0].extend(["CTR","Lower Bound","Upper Bound"])


for row in raw_data[1:]:
    phat, l_bound, u_bound  = confidence(row[2],row[3])
    row.extend([phat, l_bound, u_bound])



# raw_data[1:].sort(key=lambda x: x[6], reverse=True) 

sorted(raw_data[1:], key=itemgetter(6), reverse=True)



outputfile= open('outputfile.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(outputfile,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

wr.writerows(raw_data)


raw_data_csv.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Can anybody tell why?
Thanks!

Comment: `sorted()` returns a *new list* but you are ignoring that. You say you tried `list.sort()` too; can you show us how you did that?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. it's commented out just above.

Comment: (just above the sorted() line). If I need to assign the result of sorted() to a new list -  what's the most elegant way to have the header in the new list? I used new_list.insert(0,raw_data[0]). (Oh - and I used new_list to assign sorted() to and it works :) )

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting a *slice* in one attempt (which creates a new list object), and in your other attempt you ignore the return value of `sorted()`.

You cannot sort part of a list like that; create a new list by concatenating instead:

```
rows = rows[:1] + sorted(raw_data[1:], key=itemgetter(6), reverse=True)
```

Comment: thanks! what would it look like if I wanted to sort in place? Is it better to use itemgetter or lambda?

Comment: @Optimesh: then *remove* the first row from the list first; `header = rows.pop(0)` perhaps.