# Why sorting is not working here?Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone tell me why sorting is not working here?

```
    b = input()
    list1  = input().split()
    c = input() 
    list2 = input().split()
    set1 = set(list1)
    set2 = set(list2)
    list3 = list(set1.union(set2) - set1.intersection(set2))
    sorted(list3)
    print(list3)
```

in put format :

4

2 4 5 9

4

2 4 11 12

Comment: please add the expected output - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort (and sorted) not sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824804/sort-and-sorted-not-sorting)

Comment: Just to note that: `set1.union(set2) - set1.intersection(set2)` can be written as `set1.symmetric_difference(set2)`...

Answer (score 1):

sorted does not sort in place. Use

```
list4 = sorted(list3)
```

and print that. See f.e. here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted

> Return value from sorted()
>   sorted() method returns a sorted list from the given iterable.

Answer (score 0):

[`sorted(list3)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a new list.

Either assign it to a variable

```
list3 = sorted(list3)
```

or use the [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method to change the list in-place.

```
list3.sort()
```

For more on Python sorting, have a look at [Sorting HOW TO](https://portal.care360.com/care360/care360.login) from the official Python documentation

Comment: That too is not working, output is still  ['11', '12', '5', '9']!

Comment: @Nexus because you want to make them integers first, no? The sorting is correct for strings...

Comment: @Nexus Those are sorted strings.  If you expect them to be integers, then make them integers beforehand: `list3 = [int(x) for x in list3]`   Otherwise, you can use a key function to sort them as if they were `int`s.  `list3.sort(key=int)`

Comment: @Nexus: see, you didn't explain very well that you have *string values*. Use `sorted(list3, key=int)` then.

Comment: Yes! That explains ! How did I miss this silly point ! :( Thanks @JonClements